# Why does the Firefox browser throw an error with PHP code?

Tags: php

I'm running a small loop to get the number of items in an array stored in local storage. Then passed to a Session Variable. I tried using Count() but that threw an error. So I then tried  this code but I get the following error:- Any clues?

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in --etc. directory code line

```
$ItemCount = 0;
        $Data = json_decode($_SESSION['ItemArray']);
        foreach($Data as $item){
            $ItemCount = $ItemCount+1;
        }
```

Comment: $Data is not an array or an iterable object.

Comment: FYI it is not the firefox browser who is telling you the error

Answer (score 0):

$Data is not an array or an iterable object. Add a second parameter to [json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode) to get an array returned.

```php
$ItemCount = 0;
$Data = json_decode($_SESSION['ItemArray'], true);
foreach($Data as $item){
    $ItemCount = $ItemCount+1;
}
```

Comment: Provided some assumptions on the data structure which OP didnt really provide

Comment: @GetSet Error message is clear about that. An empty array would not cause any error.

Comment: Makes sense, however we dont know what is coming out of "session" based on non-existent OP code on that demonstration, nor are we clued in on a data structure by same source. I might add, OP seems to have abandoned commenting her/himself further indicating a "we will never know" scenario.

Comment: I don't know what to discuss. The error said, it is no array. Independent what he is putting in, it does not change the issue.

Comment: I get you. However perhaps your remark should be comments level since we dont know OP other logical errors being blind to a data structure

Comment: Providing code in comments is awful (in current SO comment formatting). That's why made it as an answer, too. As you can see I already commented it.